# Python Flask End To End Encryption Behind AWS ALB

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ssl, flask, amazon-ecs

I've a Python 3 Flask app running in an ECS cluster. The Flask app is configured to run in SSL mode. The app can't be accessed via the ALB Cname, as it generates connection refused as seen here -

```
curl -Il https://tek-app.example.com/health
curl: (7) Failed to connect to tek-app.example.com port 443: Connection refused
```

When the ALB is hit directly and ignoring the SSL cert exception, it works as seen here -

```
curl -Il -k https://tek-w-appli-1234.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/health
HTTP/2 200 
date: Sun, 24 Feb 2019 14:49:27 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 9
server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.7.2
```

I understand the main recommendation is to run it behind a Nginx or Apache proxy and to set the X-Forward headers via their configs, but I feel this is over engineering the solution.

I've also tried enabling the following in the app -

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
...
app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
...
```

And this fix now produces the correct source IP's in the Cloudwatch logs, but doesn't allow connections via the ALB Cname.

Is there something simple that I'm missing here?

## Reply to first answer

Thank you - the Cname is pointing to the correct ALB. I ran into a similar issue two weeks back with an Apache server, and the fix was to ensure X-Forward-Proto was in use in the Apache vhosts.conf file. So I'm thinking this may be something similar.

Comment: `Connection refused` implies that the DNS name isn't pointing to the right address and nothing is listening on port 443. Double check that `tek-app.example.com` is pointing to the correct load balancer with it's CNAME. Alternatively, if you are using Route 53, use an Alias.

Answer (score 0):

I did it again - while developing locally I edited my /etc/hosts file to have a local entry to play with. Then when the Flask app was pushed to the cloud and tested from the same desktop, it was referencing the local DNS entry as opposed to the public equivalent, thus the connection refused. With the local entry removed, all is now working.